# Finger Print Reader Dell G5 5587 15inch

Tags: hardware, security, user

I have no idea how to enable the finger print reader in order to login.. Side not how could I get fingerprint reader to then enter sudo password when required in the terminal?

Answer (score 0):

You can try use `fingerprint-gui`

it is little old post in Ubuntu StackExchange but you can follow this discution [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/193528/how-to-enable-fingerprint-device-for-thinkpad-t430s-in-12-04)